# NaN error in countdown timer on magento Any idea why?

Tags: javascript, php, magento, timer, countdown

I am making a countdown timer for a eCommerce page on magento platform I got some help for the coding online this is the Java Script coding :

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function Countdown(then) {

    this.then = then;

    function setElement(id, value) {
        if (value.length < 2) {
            value = "0" + value;
        }

        window.document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
    }

    function countdown() {
        now  = new Date("");
        diff = new Date("this.then - now");

        seconds_left  = Math.floor(diff.valueOf() / 1000);

        seconds  = Math.floor(seconds_left / 1) % 60;
        minutes  = Math.floor(seconds_left / 60) % 60;
        hours    = Math.floor(seconds_left / 3600) % 24;
        days     = Math.floor(seconds_left / 86400) % 86400;

        setElement('countdown-days', days);
        setElement('countdown-hours', hours);
        setElement('countdown-minutes', minutes);
        setElement('countdown-seconds', seconds);

        countdown.timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }

    function start() {
        this.timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }

    start(then);
 }

 Countdown(new Date(""));
</script>
```

I am getting an error NaN days NaN:NaN:
I cannot figure out why. I need some help in this
The special price start date in the magento's backend is 1/8/2016 and the end date is 1/14/2016. where I am going wrong?

Comment: your `diff` and `now` variables are an invalid date - the syntax you've used in the date constructor isn't even close to how javascript works - you may need to brush up on some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Available Syntax for `Date` function are as shown below

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

your case is none of the above.

what you are trying to do is(simplified)

```
now  = new Date("");
t = new Date("");
console.log(new Date("t - now"))
```

which prints **Invalid Date**

[More about date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Use this script, it is working fine.

```
<script>
    var end = new Date('2016-10-26 00:00:00');
    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;
    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }
    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cracked the code.
Make sure the format you're using is:  YYYY-MM-DD-HR-MM-SS (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second).
I forgot one '0' and it gave me an error.  It worked great once I fixedd it.